# Navbar fixed falla al hacer scroll

Tags: javascript, vue.js, navbar, buefy

Hola estoy usando el componente "Navbar" de Buefy en Vue.js
Mi pagina consta de dos vistas.
En la primera vista se mantiene Fijo el menu, como se espera.
Pero a lo que voy a la otra vista el menu se esconde al hacer scroll.
Algun consejo?

Foto de Vista principal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Foto vista 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo:

```
  <!-- Header-->
       <b-navbar id="navbar-h" v-on:scroll="handleScroll"
         class="navbar-element ojo container is-widescreen is-fullhd"
          transparent
           fixed-top
            is-spaced
                   >
    <template slot="brand">
        <b-navbar-item href="/" id="bajar">
           <img v-if="window.width<1200 && window.scroll<120" id="img-logo" class="img-logo" 
          src="../src/assets/img/logorespon3x.png">
          <img v-else-if="window.width<1200 && window.scroll>=120" id="img-logo" class="img-logo" 
             src="../src/assets/img/logoresponcolor.png">
            <img v-else-if="window.width>=1200 && window.scroll<120" id="img-logo" class="img-logo" 
              src="../src/assets/img/logo@2x.png">
            <img v-else-if="window.width>=1200 && window.scroll>=120" id="img-logo" class="img-logo" 
                src="../src/assets/img/logo2color.png">
                  </b-navbar-item>
              </template>
               <template slot="end">
               <div class="columns" id="columns-header">
              <div class="column" id="columna-inicio">
          <b-navbar-item class="active" href="/" id="bar1">
            <p class="inicio" id="inicio1">Inicio</p>
            </b-navbar-item>
           </div>
              <div class="column">
              <b-navbar-item href="/sistema">
            <p class="sistema" id="sistema1">Sistema</p>
                 </b-navbar-item>
                 </div>
               <div class="column" id="Columna-btn" v-on:click="cambio">
                <b-navbar-item tag="router-link" :to="{name:'Paciente'}" id="btnCotizacion1" 
            class="active">
           <p class="cotizaciones-btn"  id="btnCambio" >Cotizaciones</p>
            </b-navbar-item>
                </div>
                </div>

                </template>
             </b-navbar>

             <router-view/>
```

Comment: ¿Se queda fija, pero debajo del contenido? Intenta asignarle en CSS un `z-index` alto.

Comment: css > {position:fixed!important.; z-index:2000!important}

Comment: No no , no se esconde es como que se queda arriba porque al hacer scroll arriba desde esa posicion si se muestra como es. Pero deberia funcionar correctamente al hacer scroll hacia abajo y mostrar todo el menu